# Send email in trigger and handle errors when email template is not found

Tags: apex, trigger

I have a public page published in community. This page is basically a web form which gathers information. Once the form is submitted a new record of MyObject__c is created. One of the requirements is that when a record is created an email with a confirmation link should be sent to the person who submitted the form. Only after the email address has been confirmed the MyObject__c record can be processed.

Emails are sent in an after insert trigger. The email message is derived from a template. Below is the sample code. **Please note, I put all the code in trigger here for brevity**

```
trigger MyObjectTrigger on MyObject__c (after insert)
{
    List<MyObject__c> myObjects = (List<MyObject__c>) Trigger.new;
    EmailTemplate template;

    private void sendValidationEmail()
    {
        template = getEmailTemplate();
        if (template == null) { return; }

        List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> messages = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
        for (MyObject__c myObject : myObjects) {
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage message = composeEmailMessage(myObject);
            messages.add(message);
        }
        Messaging.sendEmail(messages);
    }

    private Messaging.SingleEmailMessage composeEmailMessage(MyObject__c record)
    {
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage message =
                Messaging.renderStoredEmailTemplate(template.Id, null, record.Id);
        message.setSaveAsActivity(true);
        message.setToAddresses(new String[]{
                record.Email_Address__c
        });
        return message;
    }

    private EmailTemplate getEmailTemplate()
    {
        My_Settings__c mySettings = My_Settings__c.getInstance();
        String templateDeveloperName = mySettings.My_Email_Template__c;
        EmailTemplate template = null;
        EmailTemplate[] emailTemplates = [SELECT Id FROM EmailTemplate WHERE DeveloperName = :templateDeveloperName LIMIT 1];
        if (!emailTemplates.isEmpty()) { template = emailTemplates[0]; }
        return template;
    }
}
```

The question that concerns me is how do a situation when the needed email template is missing. It can happen that it was deleted by accident. In such a case `getEmailTemplate()` will return `null` and an exception will be thrown. And this will not be a pleasant experience either for users or for developer who will debug that later.

So I have two ideas on how to address it. One, which is currently implemented, do not proceed and return immediately if the email template is missing. Users will not see an error and the record will be saved successfully. But in this case an email will not be sent, and user will not know about this.

Another option is to use an `addError()` on all `myObjects` and then return. This time users will be notified about the error, but the record will not be saved.

Which approach is better and are there even better ways to handle this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My option would be when there is no email template to:

- send the customer (and BCC the sysad) a `default email (without a template)` with as much useful contextual data so the community user feels they were "heard" and that a followup is forthcoming
- Use normal apex outbound emails with a `setBody()` to contain the text.

Another amelioration would be a surveillance system that was a scheduled job that ran every x hours looking for email templates, configured in the custom setting, that are now missing.

This would catch the error after the fact and some community users might be affected until the problem is fixed.  For low use templates though, this might be a good solution

Another amelioration in conjunction with the above would be to put the templates in a folder where edit access was tightly restricted and that the template descriptions contained all sorts of warnings about do not delete without also changing the custom settings references

Answer (score 1):

A third and, in my opinion, the best approach would be to log the failure to a custom object and allow the trigger to succeed.

If you can't find the email template, write to an object called something like `Unsent_Email__c`, with all the required details. Then, an admin can have a scheduled report or dashboard or email alert on that object.

The admin can go in, fix the problem, and choose whether or not it is appropriate to send the unsent emails.

It's quite a lot more work, but it's the best way to make sure that information doesn't get lost.